# Interpolate data with non fixed time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, data-science, interpolation

So I have a dataset that looks like this:

| A header | Timestamp | A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1624023687 | 3766 |
| 1 | 1624023687 | 3767 |
| 2 | 1624023687 | 110 |
| 3 | 1624023687 | 3762 |
| 4 | 1624023687 | 3770 |
| 5 | 1624023687 | 108 |
| 6 | 1624023687 | 3765 |
| 7 | 1624023690 | 3768 |
| 8 | 1624023690 | 3768 |
| 9 | 1624023690 | 111 |
| 10 | 1624023690 | 3760 |
| 11 | 1624023690 | 3765 |
| 12 | 1624023690 | 111 |
| 13 | 1624023690 | 3765 |
| 14 | 1624023690 | 3762 |
| 15 | 1624023690 | 109 |
| 16 | 1624023690 | 3774 |
| 17 | 1624023690 | 3760 |
| 18 | 1624023690 | 112 |
| 19 | 1624023690 | 3761 |
| 20 | 1624023692 | 109 |
| 21 | 1624023692 | 3764 |
| 22 | 1624023692 | 3767 |
| 23 | 1624023692 | 104 |
| 24 | 1624023692 | 3769 |

As you can see, I have multiple rows with the same timestamp and I want to have a different timestamp for each rows. I thought about using a smaller fraction of time and interpolate, but the problem is I don't have the same count of rows within each timestamp nor a fixed step in time.
This is the result of a group by command:

```
pd.Dataframe(df.grroupby(['timestamp'])['A'].count())
```

[image: GroupBy(timestamp)]

How can I get a different timestamp for each row ?

Comment: Do you care *how* the timestamps would be interpolated? What is the `groupby` supposed to tell us? Also, could you add the sample data as text instead of screenshot? copy&paste is much simpler than OCR...

Comment: For now no, I was thinking like count how many rows each timestamp has and devide the time intervall betweeen t and t+x by the number of rows and add that fraction of seconds to the time  . But this solutions seems too "manual" so I was wondering if there s a better way .  The group by is just to show that I don't have a fixed number of rows for each time .Thank you

Comment: maybe you can take each timestamp that is different to the previous, and do a linear interpolation of the gaps in-between, does this sound like an option?

Comment: The data represents the evolution of a mesure in time .So first, I want to just change the timestamp of each row (by adding a fraction of the gap between timestamps for example). Then when I have different timestamps for all rows , do a linear interpolation to fill the gaps